# Why $\frac{d^2u}{dx}=2u\cdot \frac{du}{dx}$

Tags: derivatives

I don't see why the below expression is correct:

$\frac{d^2u}{dx}=2u\cdot \frac{du}{dx}$

I believe it's rather easy, but I can't see how it is correct. Can anyone tell me why the above equation is correct?

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not correct for general $u$, just think of $u(x) = x$, but: if you have a typo (that seems possible, as $\frac{d^2 u}{dx}$ does not make sense) and have the equation
$$ \frac{d{(u^{\color{red}2}})}{dx} = 2u \frac{du}{dx} $$
this is correct by the chain rule, as $\frac{d(u^2)}{du} = 2u$.

Comment: Great, thank you. I misunderstood what my teacher was writing/saying. $\frac{d(u^2)}{dx}$ must have been the left side of the equation as you wrote.

Comment: If we then integrate $\frac{1}{2}\int_x1^x2{\frac{d(u^2)}{dx}dx}$, would we then get $\frac{1}{2}((u_x2)^2-(u_x1)^2}$ or $((u_x2)^2-(u_x1)^2}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact it isn't correct, look at my picture for understanding the answer [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjViO.png)